# Issue: [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object

Tags: node.js

How can I fix the below issue? I am unable to submit the form as apparently the listener should be a function. I am using Node Version 14.1.0.

Error:

```
 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object
```

Relevant Code:

```
app.post("/about", function(req, res){
  const email = req.body.email;

  const data = {
    members: [
      {
        email_address: email,
        status: "subscribed"
      }
    ]
  };

  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

  const url = process.env.CUST_KEY;

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    auth: process.env.API_KEY
  }

  const request = https.request(url, options, function(response) {

    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.render("success");
    } else {
      res.render("failure");
    }

    response.on("data", function(data){
    })
  })

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});
```

Comment: Same issue here. 2nd arg(options) lands as cb.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, which adds the url within the options and shifts some other stuff around:

```
 app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    
      const email = req.body.email;
   
      // console.log(emailEntry);
    
      const data = {
        members: [{
          email_address: email,
          status: "subscribed"
        }]
      };
    
      const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)
    
      const options = {
        url: "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/LIST_ID",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "auth API_KEY"
        },
        body: jsonData
      }
    
      request(options, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
          res.redirect("tryagain");
        } else {
          if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.redirect("success");
          } else {
            res.redirect("tryagain");
          }
        }
      });
    });
```